# C++ Reading from text file data type as struct using getline

Tags: c++

I have a text file in form:

```
a 1 b 6 e 4 h 2
r 5 q 1 a 2 e 2 b 3
```

up to 300k line. every char follows with its value. I want to read this file line by line, and do pair between each 2 chars in the same line. the results of first line:

```
(a,b)
(a,e)
(a,h)
(b,e)
(b,h)
(e,h)
```

I also, count the frequency for each pair. The code for that:

```
    using namespace std;

    std::map<std::pair< char, int>, int>  CharP;

    struct Mydata
    {
        char myString;
        float value;


         friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Mydata  &d) {
        {
                    string line;
            std::getline(is,line);
            return is >> d.myString>> d.value;

        }
    };


    int main()
    {
        std::ifstream in("Data.txt");



            std::vector<Mydata> data{ std::istream_iterator<Mydata>(in), std::istream_iterator<Mydata>() };

            for (std::vector<Mydata> ::iterator current = data.begin(); current != data.end(); ++current)
            {
                char a = current->myString;
                for (std::vector<Mydata> ::iterator current2 = ++current; current2 != data.end(); ++current2)
                {
                    char b = current2->myString;

                    auto itt = CharP.find(std::make_pair(b, a));

                    ++CharP[(itt != CharP.end()) ? std::make_pair(b, a) : std::make_pair(a, b)];

                } 
--current;

            }





        cout << " \nPress any key to continue\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

I got this error:
 binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Mydata' (or there is no acceptable conversion).

I have another concern, since I have large file, I'm wondering if there is another method faster than the attached code.

Comment: Instead of using a vector ... why not use a `std::map`?

Comment: I would replace `auto itt = CharP.find(std::make_pair(b, a)); (itt != CharP.end())` with `b<a`.  It's FAR faster, and the differences in results seem to be within your intended results.

Comment: @mooing-duck I noticed this comment 3 hours ago, and since then I tried to use b<a but I couldn't fix error. I just want to know why using ( < ) it's far faster? I also did compare the time between your code [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a89c8824bfe2354) and mine, and your code is faster.

Comment: Your code for each pair `a,b` searches the binary tree for if `b,a` already exists, and then if so it will find the node at `b,a` _again_ and then update it, otherwise it will find the node at `a,b` and update that.  Mine skips a binary tree search by consistently using the `a,b` pair where `a<=b`.

Comment: @mooing-duck you're right, your code is fast,  but still I want to update the pair's value whether a,b is found or b,a. thanks

Comment: @Sandy: Right, because in your code, you don't know if a,b is already in the tree, or if b,a is.  In my code, I _always_ know which one is in the tree, so I can skip that check.  For `a 1 b 1 a 1`, yours checks ba, updates ab, checks aa, updates aa, checks ab, updates ab.  With mine, since a<b, it updates ab.  Then since a=a it updates aa.  Then since a<b, it updates ab again.  Because a,b and b,a are _always_ stored in the tree as ab since a<b.  With yours, you have to check every time because you don't know if you stored as ab or as ba.

Answer (score 3):

Without having looked at the rest of the code I think I can safely say this is the problem:

> ```
> friend std::istream& getline(std::istream &is, Mydata &d)
> ```

Were you intending on overloading the *extractor* in this declaration? If so, you should know that the extractor is an *operator*, namely `operator>>()`. Replace the `getline` with `>>`:

> ```
> friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Mydata &d);
> ```

Also, the following is **very** unreadable:

> ```
> ++CharP[(itt != CharP.end()) ? std::make_pair(b, a) : std::make_pair(a, b)];
> ```

replace it with this:

> ```
>  if (itt != CharP.end())
>  {
>      auto p = std::make_pair(b, a);
>      ++CharP[p];
>  } else
>  {
>      auto p = std::make_pair(a, b);
>      ++CharP[p];
>  }
> ```

Comment: Thank you. I used (operator>>) but I thought if I use getline I can extract line by line, not the whole data in file at once. Because I want to extract each line separately and do some processing in this line.

Comment: in this part: `std::vector<Mydata> data{ std::istream_iterator<Mydata>(in), std::istream_iterator<Mydata>() };`

Comment: @Sandy Keep in mind that `istream_iterator` will use `operator>>`, which is why you must overload it, and not create a friend `getline` function.

Comment: @Sandy You can use `std::getline()` inside the extractor definition.

Comment: @0x499602D2: That's not useful since he wants to read many `MyData`, and that's the extractor for reading a single `MyData`.

Comment: @MooingDuck TBH I'm not entirely sure what he wants to do with the line. If he were more specific I would suggest something more suitable for his needs.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I got the impression he wanted to effectively run the program once per line of input.

Comment: @zac-howland @0x499602d2 I edited my code by using std::getline() inside the extractor definition  `&operator>>` . Then, I traced the program to understand the process. After using std::getline(), it extract lines one by one, but `data`has only the first entry in each line (except the first line)!. Can you please give me an example

Comment: @0x499602D2: I think he wants [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a89c8824bfe2354)

Comment: @Sandy I think you should apply [@MooingDucks's code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a89c8824bfe2354). It shows you the correct way to implement it.

Comment: @MooingDucks's code is exactly what I need. Unfortunately, I can’t accept his answer, or vote for all of you because I have less than 15 reputation